# How do I split HTML/XML text between HTML <br> tags?

Tags: xpath

I am using a document that has html and text like the code below:

```
text1
<br/>
text2
<a><b>text2</b></a>
<br/>
<br/>
text3
```

What I want to do is to extract each line in turn.  Like the example below:

```
1) text1
2) text2 text2
3) text3
```

in an array.  How would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of XPath do you use? Any chance to use XQuery or XSLT 2.0 instead? In XSLT 2.0 you could easily use `<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="br"><xsl:sequence select="string-join(current-group()/descendant-or-self::text()/normalize-space(), ' ')"/></xsl:for-each-group>`.

Comment: Could you please show XQuery implementation too?

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent in XQuery 1.0 to XSLT 2.0's `for-each-group group-ending-with` so I can't give you a direct translation of my XSLT 2.0 suggestion. XQuery 3.0 has some more advanced grouping features but I am not familiar with it so someone else needs to help with that if you can use an XQuery 3.0 implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish would be to select all text nodes and all br tags:

```
//text() | //br
```

Then iterate through the results to create your array with concatenated strings.